# Can I create a keyboard shortcut/hotkey to a tile in Windows 8 Start Screen?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

If yes, How can I do it?

PS: Please, consider tiles with Modern UI (Metro) apps AND tiles with traditional Windows apps.

Answer (score 2):

This only works, as far as I know, on traditional Windows apps, but it works on both Windows 7 and 8.

Right click a shortcut on the desktop, or in a folder, and enter Properties.
One of the textboxes is named "Shortcut Key". In there you can press a key, for a shortcut of Ctrl + Alt + Key, or any modifier for various effects. You can also use F1, F2, F3 etc.., without modifiers.

To find the shortcut of a tile, right click it and click on Go to location. It should lead you to the location of the tile.
I do not know if this works with Metro Apps. As far as I know, there are two places where the Start Screen gets its shortcuts from, but I'm not sure where those are right now.

edit: Piece of advice: Do not set a program to F5, and try to refresh a webpage repeatedly, like.. 20 times in a row. It will start 20 instances of that application...